# How can identical types fail to match

Tags: c, gtk, cairo

I'm trying to implement in my GTK 2.0 application the advice from question [How to create a cairo_t on a Gtk 2 window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21102622/how-to-create-a-cairo-t-on-a-gtk-2-window), and I am perplexed by the result.  The error output is

```
planes_view.c: In function ‘draw_lines_planes’:
planes_view.c:145:33: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘gdk_cairo_create’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
   cr = gdk_cairo_create((struct GdkDrawable *)(view->drawing_area));
                             ^
In file included from /usr/include/gtk-2.0/gdk/gdk.h:33:0,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-2.0/gtk/gtk.h:32,
                 from planes_view.h:35,
                 from planes_view.c:34:
/usr/include/gtk-2.0/gdk/gdkcairo.h:33:10: note: expected ‘struct GdkDrawable *’ but argument is of type ‘struct GdkDrawable *’
 cairo_t *gdk_cairo_create            (GdkDrawable        *drawable);
         ^
```

Note that the two conflicting types are identical.  How can this be?  Perhaps two types with the same name?  Even if so, I need to know how to do this right.

The offending line was originally

```
cr = gdk_cairo_create(view->drawing_area);
```

And the complaint was that the drawing area's declared type is GtkWidget *, so I tried a normal typecast thus:

```
cr = gdk_cairo_create((struct GdkDrawable *)(view->drawing_area));
```

with the results shown above.

Comment: Can you cut it down to a minimal compilable example?  (My gut instinct tells me that you've got incompatible defs of what the struct is, but I don't think that's quite the error you'd see.)

Comment: try to remove the keyword "struct". I guess GdkDrawable is already a typedef.

Comment: You can't just cast things to something they're not (GtkWidget is not a GdkDrawable). The GdkDrawable you want is probably `view->drawing_area->window`, but why not do what I did in the original answer: `widget->window` (assuming the first argument of the expose handler is called widget)? ... actually now that I think about it: `gtk_widget_get_window (widget)` would be the best way.

Answer (score 1):

Trust the compiler. A `struct GdkDrawable *` is not the same as a `GdkDrawable *`. `GdkDrawable` is already a typedef to a struct:

`typedef struct _GdkDrawable GdkDrawable;`

And as jku said, you're messing things up. `gdk_cairo_create` expects a `GdkDrawable`, and you're trying to feed it a GtkWidget. Your `GdkDrawable` is the `GdkWindow` that is stored inside the `GtkWidget` (the `window` member), that you can access using `gtk_widget_get_window`.

Answer (score 0):

I would say you have incompatible definitions of the symbol, or that you somehow compile this symbol several times. Check the visibility of the symbol.

Comment: That's no help at all.  The struct comes from GTK/cairo headers.  My code does not define it.

Comment: Moreover, beyond that I have no idea how to check "visibility", or indeed what that is in C.